# Pattern matching in excel (several columns)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a range 100+ rows and 5 columns. I want to match pattern of 5 columns in a row. Data and pattern have duplicates and there is no sequence or sorting creteria. Data and pattern are random. Iwant to return if a certain pattern ‘matches’ with any rows in range.

Thanks.

Data Range sample:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EL | OH | EH | OH | OL |
| OL | EH | EL | OL | OH |
| OH | EH | EL | OL | OL |
| EH | OL | EH | OL | OH |

Pattern to match:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OL | OL | EL | OH | EH |

Result: It should return match at row three in the range.

Comment: Can you be more clear why it matches at row three? Why not row two? What if there are more patterns matching? Do you want to return all matching patterns? What did you try yourself?

Comment: It should match rows 2 and 3 shouldn't it?  Paste this into F1 on your data sheet and copy down: `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,SORT(Data!A1:E1,1,1,TRUE))=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,SORT(Pattern!$A$1:$E$1,1,1,TRUE))`

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to Byrow in Excel 365, you can use:

```
LET(range,A2:E5,
key,G2:K2,
sortKey,SORT(key,,,TRUE),
FILTER(range,BYROW(range,LAMBDA(array,SUM(--(SORT(array,,,TRUE)=sortKey))))=5))
```

or as suggested by @Jerry Jeremiah's comment

```
=LET(range,A2:E5,
key,G2:K2,
sortKey,TEXTJOIN(",",1,SORT(key,,,TRUE)),
FILTER(range,BYROW(range,LAMBDA(array,TEXTJOIN(",",1,SORT(array,,,TRUE))=sortKey))))
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful @Tom Sharpe

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
=IF(CONCAT(B2,C2,D2,E2,F2)=J2,"Match Found",0)
```

[image: Example]

You can [generate all your permutations](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/generate_all_permutations.htm) and later on check with the CONCAT function above